# How to get virtual box performance details?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I have Virtualbox in which I installed Ubuntu server 12.4. Now I am doing load testing on this virtual machine by sending number of requests. Now I want to get performance details of that virtual machine. In Ubuntu server there is no GUI installed.

Comment: Are you using a GUI for you OS or are you working without?

Comment: Can you clarify which performance details you need? It sound like you just need to tun top.